# Extension .php is added to filelink before the link itself

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an Issue with my include file path in Wordpress.

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register( 'FollowUp_autoloader' );

function FollowUp_autoloader( $calledclass ) 
{

    $namespace = 'FollowUp';
    
    if (strpos( $calledclass, $namespace ) !== 0) 
    {
        return;
    }
    
    $calledclass = str_replace( $namespace, '', $calledclass );
    
    $filepath = trim( str_replace( '\\', '/', $calledclass ), "/" ) . '.php';

    if ( file_exists( $filepath) )
    {
        require_once( $filepath );
    }
}
?>
```

I get an error the file does not exists and if I print the $filepath variable I see I mistake in the link.

Output: **.phpinc/pages/activate.php** The extension .php is printed before the file link.

I tried this below but do not fix my issue

```
$filepath = trim( str_replace( '\\', '/', $calledclass ), "/" );
```

Output: **inc/pages/activate** <- without any extension

In the file where the autoloader is required I use this

```
use FollowUp\inc\ages\activate;
```

Does somebody know this issue ?

Comment: Try adding it in the line after the `trim(str_replace(...))` instead and see if that works? `$filepath .= '.php';`. However, I can't reproduce this issue with the posted code: https://3v4l.org/RtJqH

Comment: Hi Magnus I tried this but the issue is still there. I tried also what you did in the generator but I think this is an conflict in Wordpress?

Comment: Wordpress can't change how concatenation in PHP works. Can you show us the full "file doesn't exist"-error message you get?

Comment: I have searching and I know the problem. If I activate the plugin the autoloader is running but the parameter is empty and this returns .php. After that Wordpress is fire the plugin again and now the parameter has a value and paste this directly to .php.